# WebService call from Orbeon form

Tags: web-services, orbeon, xforms

Please help with sample code for web service call and handling response while clicking on a button with xforms or orbeon form.

Answer (score 0):

Request:

```
<xforms:instance id="ws-request-instance">     <!-- Field XML Instance -->                          
                                            <soapenv:Envelope>
                                               <soapenv:Header/>
                                               <soapenv:Body>

                                               </soapenv:Body>
                                            </soapenv:Envelope>
                            </xforms:instance>
```

Response Template:

```
                            <xforms:instance id="ws-response-instance">  <!-- Field XML Instance -->                          
                                            <soapenv:Envelope>
                                            </soapenv:Envelope>
                            </xforms:instance>
```

Search action:

```
 <xforms:submission id="" ref="instance('ws-request-instance')" 
                                                            action="endpoint-url" method="post" mediatype="application/xml"
                                                            replace="instance" instance="ws-response-instance">
                                               <xforms:message ev:event="xforms-submit-done" level="modal">Done</xforms:message>
                                               <xforms:message ev:event="xforms-submit-error" level="modal">Error</xforms:message>
                                            </xforms:submission>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a Sandbox runnable code which uses webservice calls in Orbeon Form in the below discussion.

http://orbeon-forms-ops-users.24843.n4.nabble.com/calling-web-service-from-orbeon-td35438.html